# GMail doesnt show HTML-/Inline-part of eMail sent with JavaMail API

Tags: java, html, gmail, jakarta-mail, inline

Whenever I had problem with Java I always found an answer on stackoverflow without the need to ask a question on my own, but this time even Google cant help me. I just cant figure out the exact problem and try to KISS my question.

When I receive and open a mail created & sent with JavaMail API, everything is fine in Thunderbird. The HTML-part shows up with it's inline-image and the plain text is at the bottom, but Gmail wont show the HTML-part. Instead it just shows the plaintext and only the attachment (so my inline-image isnt visible at all). Gmail says the eMail ist not encoded and I am not sure if this may cause the problem.

The structure of the mail is as followed:

```
    - MimeMultipart mixed
    -- BodyPart (attachment)
    -- BodyPart (as a container)
    --- MimeMultipart alternative
    ---- BodyPart (plaintext)
    ---- BodyPart (as a second container)
    ----- MimeMultipart related
    ------ BodyPart (html)
    ------ BodyPart (inline)
```

Part where I create the message:

```
    MimeBodyPart BPhtml = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPhtml.setContent("<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body>Take a look at this image:<br><br><IMG src=\"cid:fileNamePlusUniqueHash\"></body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    MimeBodyPart BPinline = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPinline.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(pathToImage)));
    BPinline.setFileName(fileName);
    // Note: my CID is a combination of the image's fileName and a salt/hash - unique:
    BPinline.setHeader("Content-ID", "<fileNamePlusUniqueHash>");
    BPinline.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);

    MimeMultipart MPrel = new MimeMultipart("related");
    MPrel.addBodyPart(BPhtml);
    MPrel.addBodyPart(BPinline);

    MimeBodyPart BPcon1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPcon1.setContent(MPrel);

    MimeBodyPart BPplain = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPplain.setText("Plain text", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    MimeMultipart MPalt = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
    MPalt.addBodyPart(BPcon1);
    MPalt.addBodyPart(BPplain);

    MimeBodyPart BPcon2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPcon2.setContent(MPalt);

    MimeBodyPart BPattach = new MimeBodyPart();
    BPattach.attachFile(new File(pathToAttachment));

    MimeMultipart MPmx = new MimeMultipart();
    MPmx.addBodyPart(BPcon2);
    MPmx.addBodyPart(BPattach);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(properties, null));
    message.setContent(MPmx);

    // ... set recipients, sender, subject, e.g. ...

    Transport.send(message);
```

Source of eMail:

```
    [...] (delivered, received, subject, e.g., ask for more if important)

    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
            boundary="----=_Part_0_1248658274.1455785789602"

    ------=_Part_0_1248658274.1455785789602
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
            boundary="----=_Part_1_860340994.1455785789629"

    ------=_Part_1_860340994.1455785789629
    Content-Type: multipart/related; 
            boundary="----=_Part_2_743690907.1455785789629"

    ------=_Part_2_743690907.1455785789629
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>Take a look at this image:<br><br></html><IMG src="cid:blabla.pngPlusUniqueHash"></body>

    ------=_Part_2_743690907.1455785789629
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=blabla.png
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: inline; filename=blabla.png
    Content-ID: <blabla.pngPlusUniqueHash>
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPEAAAEdCAIAAABSWBYTAAAYpklEQVR4nO2dXawkR3mGR4 [...] (some hundred lines more)

    ------=_Part_2_743690907.1455785789629--

    ------=_Part_1_860340994.1455785789629
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    plain text

    ------=_Part_1_860340994.1455785789629--

    ------=_Part_0_1248658274.1455785789602
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=blabla.pdf
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blabla.pdf
    UEsDBBQACAgIAERuSEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAARW50aXR5U3RvcmXsfQl8G8W5+NqxfM [...] (some hundred lines more)

    ------=_Part_0_1248658274.1455785789602--
```

I tried a lot of different methods to add the attachment/inline (InputStreamReader e.g.) but nothing changed. Could you help me to find the mistake? I speculate on an incorrect construction of the message.

Best regards, Fenrir

**EDIT**
I sent the mail to another provider (GMX) and have no problems with the presentation of the HTML-part, so I guess it's a problem with Gmail itself. Is there a best practice to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

So I tried some different mail-constructions and finally got a working Gmail-mail! But the solution is strange and I still dont understand it.

The only thing I changed is the Multipart-Alternative MimeType. Instead of using

```
MPalt = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
```

I changed it to

```
MPalt = new MimeMultipart();
```

and then added the HTML-BodyPart and Inline-BodyPart to it. But in my opinion this makes no sense - can somebody explain this weird behavior?

Note: There is no difference between the not-working mail-source-'code' and the working mail-source-code. I am confused.

Best regards, Fenrir

**EDIT:**

Click for screenshot: [AT = Attachment, HT = HTML, PL = Plain, IN = Inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Zet.png)

I made a screenshot of my Gmail-inbox and as you can see Google has only problems with PLINHT (a mail created with plain, html and an inline-image) and PLINHTAT.

```
    case PLINHTAT:
        mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

        bpHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpHtml.setContent(this.htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        mpRel = new MimeMultipart("related");
        mpRel.addBodyPart(bpHtml);

        bpInlines = this.getInlineAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpInlines.length; i++)
            mpRel.addBodyPart(bpInlines[i]);

        bpCon1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon1.setContent(mpRel);

        bpPlain = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpPlain.setText(this.plainText);

        mpAlt = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        mpAlt.addBodyPart(bpPlain);
        mpAlt.addBodyPart(bpCon1);

        bpCon2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon2.setContent(mpAlt);

        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpCon2);

        bpAttaches = this.getAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpAttaches.length; i++)
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpAttaches[i]);

        break;

    case PLINHT:
        bpHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpHtml.setContent(this.htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        mpRel = new MimeMultipart("related");
        mpRel.addBodyPart(bpHtml);

        bpInlines = this.getInlineAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpInlines.length; i++)
            mpRel.addBodyPart(bpInlines[i]);

        bpCon1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon1.setContent(mpRel);

        bpPlain = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpPlain.setText(this.plainText);

        mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpCon1);
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpPlain);

        break;
```

Two working examples (ATHTIN and PLHT):

```
    case ATHTIN:
        bpHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpHtml.setContent(this.htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        mpRel = new MimeMultipart("related");
        mpRel.addBodyPart(bpHtml);

        bpInlines = this.getInlineAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpInlines.length; i++)
            mpRel.addBodyPart(bpInlines[i]);

        bpCon1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon1.setContent(mpRel);

        mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpCon1);

        bpAttaches = this.getAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpAttaches.length; i++)
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpAttaches[i]);

        break;

    case PLHT:
        bpHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpHtml.setContent(this.htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        bpPlain = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpPlain.setText(this.plainText);

        mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpPlain);
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpHtml);

        break;
```

Still no satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems I solved the problem. I have no idea whats the clue, but I'll post the working construction of the mail (which doesnt differ from the code of my previous post):

```
    case PLINHTAT:
        mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        bpHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpHtml.setContent(this.htmlText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        mpRel = new MimeMultipart("related");
        mpRel.addBodyPart(bpHtml);
        bpInlines = this.getInlineAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpInlines.length; i++)
            mpRel.addBodyPart(bpInlines[i]);
        bpCon1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon1.setContent(mpRel);
        bpPlain = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpPlain.setText(this.plainText);
        mpAlt = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        mpAlt.addBodyPart(bpPlain);
        mpAlt.addBodyPart(bpCon1);
        bpCon2 = new MimeBodyPart();
        bpCon2.setContent(mpAlt);
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpCon2);
        bpAttaches = this.getAttachmentBodyParts();
        for (int i = 0; i < bpAttaches.length; i++)
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bpAttaches[i]);
        break;
```

I am still open for explanations.
[Click to see eMail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxAG2.png)